# Add trailing slash and perform rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite requests to a new path when the request uri does not begin with /blog and also ensure that all requests have a trailing slash.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/?$
 RewriteRule ^((.*)[^/])$ $1/ [C]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/blog/?(.*)$   /blog/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid double redirect for `/blog/` request like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/blog/(.+?)/?$ /blog/$1/$2/ [R=301,L,NC]

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```